# Configure IntelliJ code style with Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Is there a way to configure the project-specific Java code style and import rules in IntelliJ with a Gradle task?

In Eclipse it is possible by copying `org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` and `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` to `$PROJECT/.settings/`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [EditorConfig](http://editorconfig.org/). It's cross platform/IDE/tool and IDEA has native support for it so it pretty much does what you want in less destructive way.

For example all my projects have the following [`.editorconfig`](https://github.com/esuomi/cradle/blob/master/.editorconfig) file:

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: http://EditorConfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

# all-encompassing default settings unless otherwise specified
[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
```

For actual code style conventions, I recommend human eye. Code style is social, not technical problem. If, however, you run some really obscure and specific formatting ruleset, you should look into [IntelliJ IDEA help: Exporting and Importing Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/exporting-and-importing-settings.html) for sharing the formatting configurations between devs.

Comment: This doesn't help. There are _many_ settings which are not supported by EditorConfig. "Code style is social" doesn't help either: As there are that many settings you have to have a centralized (i.e. version controlled) configuration... _especially_ in IDEA where every new project requires to configure everything again from scratch.

Comment: @crusy https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/accessing-default-settings.html

Comment: fyi in recent IntelliJ versions basically any IntelliJ-specific code style setting can be set via `.editorconfig`: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-code-style.html#editorconfig . from this page it might not be obvious, but completion in the file works great. the IntelliJ-specific properties start with `ij_...`.